# Add a row to a TDBGrid

Tags: c++builder, tdbgrid

I've created a TGroupBox containing 5 TEdit, a TButton and a TDBGrid.
I would like to append the content of the five TEdits in the last row of the TDBGrid when I click on the TButton.

[image: TDBGrid]

The problem is that I don't even know where to start and I can't find any correct documentation or example on the internet.
Any idea? on where to start to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDBGrid is used to link a database. To manually implement a Table simply use TStringGrid instead.
here is a piece of code for what I sought :

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  if((Edit1->Text!="")&&(Edit2->Text!="")&&(Edit3->Text!=""))
  {
    StringGrid1->RowCount=StringGrid1->RowCount+1;
    StringGrid1->Cells[0][StringGrid1->RowCount-1]=StringGrid1->RowCount-1;
    StringGrid1->Cells[1][StringGrid1->RowCount-1]=Edit1->Text;
    StringGrid1->Cells[2][StringGrid1->RowCount-1]=Edit2->Text;
    StringGrid1->Cells[3][StringGrid1->RowCount-1]=Edit3->Text;
    StringGrid1->Cells[4][StringGrid1->RowCount-1]=Edit4->Text;
    Edit1->Text="";
    Edit2->Text="";
    Edit3->Text="";
    Edit4->Text="";
  }
}
```